# Downloading video from URL works fine in mobile view , not in desktop view in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, viewport, meta-tags

I tried to create link that download video file using URL

**downloder.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Downloading.....</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://cdn71.vidorg.net/h7tock23amlbu3tf6rudlkhv3znrgvl5ybkgxdzmjq733l46rlphz4ndm7zq/Sample.mp4">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If I convert this page into mobile view on my browser(Chrome 85.0.4183.121)

[image]

If I click that link, it's works fine.

[image]

When I switched back to desktop view on chrome, It doesn't work

[image]

It shows me 'error_wrong_ip'

[image]

I tried to convert viewport on the fly, but nothing changes

```
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no');
```

**Goal** : I need some *tricks* to download on desktop mode too

I tried this for a week long, I can't make it right.

**Help me out...**

Answer (score 0):

Hello because the link is a generated link for the video to download while you have generated that link the website has used your IP address and screen size for the link so that's why it is now working on the desktop you should try with a new link. and to make a downloader you need to use the downloader file you can make it via PHP or Javascript

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with your website (html code) the problem is with this **url** `("http://cdn71.vidorg.net/h7tock23amlbu3tf6rudlkhv3znrgvl5ybkgxdzmjq733l46rlphz4ndm7zq/Sample.mp4")`

I have a solution

its simple just upload you file in google drive and click on "share" and select "change to anyone with the link" so people can access the file

and copy the url and open this website [Drive direct download link generator](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/home)
this website will help you to convert the drive viewable link into *`direct-download link`*, so when user will click that link it will *directly start to download the file*

just paste the url and click "*create direct link*"

and copy the generated url and replace this url `http://cdn71.vidorg.net/h7tock23amlbu3tf6rudlkhv3znrgvl5ybkgxdzmjq733l46rlphz4ndm7zq/Sample.mp4` to the *generated link* that's it.

Answer (score 0):

As part vidorg, there are two items considered while generating the link.

1. IP address
2. User Agent

In your case Request payload should have user agent as mobile device

**eg:**

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/XXXX) AppleWebKit/000.00 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/XX.0.XXX0.0 Mobile Safari/XXx.XX Edg/XX.XXXX.x

Try setting above user-agent in the PHP request header, link will start to work!